# Deactivate CakePHPs Test Suite

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

I've got the problem that whenever I try to reach ww.domain.com/test with CakePHP the Test Suite of CakePHP wants to load.

But I don't need it, so is there a way to deactivate this route? I couldn't find anything within core.php and routes.php.

When debug is set to 2, it loads it to choose from many options to test my application. If debug is set to 0 it just says that "this URL cannot be loaded because of the debug settings".

Answer (score -1):

Remove the test.php file that sit's in the webroot folder

Comment: Won't work, only a error pops up, saying that die file is missing.

Comment: why -1? If the file is not there it's normal the you get an error if you're trying to reach it. You don't want people accessing the test suite, remove it. You can also reroute the test url to another controller or page, but you cannot remove the route, except if you ask your users not to type the test url.